# DIfference between "at home" & "home"

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, phrasal-verbs

Consider:

> She's home.
>
> She's **at** home.

Are there any differences in meaning?

Answer (score 7):

If you mean that she is in her house, flat, or apartment, you can say either "She is home" or "She is at home", without any difference in meaning.

The only difference is syntactic. When you say "She's at home", you are using the word home as a noun.  On the other hand, when you say "She's home", you are using home as an adverb, which means at home.

Comment: "If you mean that she is in **his** house..." is "his" a typo?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: When you talk about your own home, you may omit the preposition. But when you are talking about someone else's home, you need a preposition @DJMcMayhem.

Comment: @MaulikV I know, I just thought it was strange to be talking about "her" but refer to "his".

Comment: +1 But in modern grammar, we analyze "home" as a preposition in the latter case.