# "I am at home" vs "I am home"

Tags: adverbs

Last night I was watching the movie in which I heard this phrase

> **"I am *home*"**

Actually, I am looking for explanations.
How can it be possible to say, I am ***home***?

Is it the same like

> I am ***at home***

Please explain it to me in details.

Comment: In addition to the question listed above, there is plenty more on the distinction and overlap between _home_ & _at home_: see _[Why do people say I am home](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/84703/why-do-people-say-i-am-home-instead-of-i-am-at-home), [Difference between 'home' and 'at home'](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/58164/difference-between-at-home-home), [Stay home or stay at home](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16153/stay-home-or-stay-at-home-which-is-correct-and-why)_, and _[I left them at home](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40277/i-left-them-at-home)_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are correct, though you wouldn't use them in the same context:

> Honey, I'm **home**!

Is a very popular expression which means "I'm back"! In this case, you say *I'm home* to express that you **just arrived**.

On the other hand:

> Where are you right now?
>
> -I'm **at home**, what about you?

Is used to describe where you are in a static way. It doesn't serve any other purpose than to locate you.

Comment: I'm home, is it mean, I've arrived at home?

Comment: @Idon'tknowwhoIam., yes, see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21286/im-home-or-im-at-home.