# Be home vs be at home

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

What is the difference?

- He is not home.
- He is not at home.

Can I use these two phrases interchangeably?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/58164/difference-between-at-home-home Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16153/stay-home-or-stay-at-home-which-is-correct-and-why Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40277/i-left-them-at-home

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, you can. *Home* is a strange word in that it can be a:

Noun

> I was nineteen when I left my **home** and went to college.

Adjective

> They played their first **home** game of the season.

Adverb

> What time did he get **home** last night?

Or verb

> A dozen geese **homing** to their summer nesting grounds.

---

"He is not home" uses *home* as an adverb, while "he is not at home" uses it as a noun.